# How do I adjust visibility of gridlines in ggplot chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code below creates a scatter plot and uses theme_bw with has gridlines in the background -

```
data = mtcars

data %>% 
  select(mpg, disp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp, mpg))+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  theme_bw()
```

I would like to also include some vertical and horizontal lines on the chart. However with the current gridlines, it looks a bit busy. Is there a way to further reduce the visibility of the gridlines. I don't want want remove them completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be achieved by switching to a lighter color or by reducing the opacity of the color used for the grid lines which both could be achieved via theme option `panel.grid`. Below I show the second approach. Unfortunately `element_line` has no `alpha` argument to set the opacity but you could adjust it via the hex color code:

1. I make use of the default grid line color "grey92" which has rgb values (235, 235, 235).
2. To set the opacity I use `rgb()` which as a fourth argument takes the opacity or alpha which I reduce to a value of 100:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data = mtcars

# Reduce the opacity of the grid lines: Default is 255
col_grid <- rgb(235, 235, 235, 100, maxColorValue = 255)

data %>% 
  select(mpg, disp) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(disp, mpg))+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_line(color = col_grid))
```

[image]